# Two SSL Certificates

Tags: windows, ssl, iis, backup, live

I have 2 Windows IIS servers (live and backup) running a host of Wordpress sites.  The goal is to be able to switch to the backup server if the live server goes down.  I can do this now by putting the live server's IP on the backup server. No problem, EXCEPT, the live server has a SSL certificate and the backup does not.  **So...is it possible to get 2 identical SSL certificates for 2 different servers from the same authority without causing any issues so that I can truely flip the IP addresses and everything runs smoothly?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install the same SSL certificate on both servers as long as your DNS server points to the live server. Both server should be configured with the same domain name. To automate this process, you can configure the two servers as a fail over cluster that will move the IP address from one server to another.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cc825079-b821-4a6c-afb9-3e1aef97859d/clusteringmicrosoft-failover-cluster-virtual-adapter?forum=winserverClustering